# How and when do I call method to calculate android screen size

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the dimensions(width and height) of an Activity from within it, but I keep getting both the width and the height as 0.

This is the code:

```
package com.example.android_test;

//~--- non-JDK imports --------------------------------------------------------

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;

import android.os.Bundle;


import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import org.loon.framework.android.game.core.graphics.LColor;
import org.loon.framework.android.game.core.graphics.LFont;
import org.loon.framework.android.game.core.graphics.device.LGraphics;
import org.loon.framework.android.game.core.graphics.device.LGraphicsAndroid2D;
import org.loon.framework.android.game.core.graphics.geom.Dimension;


public class WordTest extends Activity  implements Runnable{ 
private transient Thread timer;
        Dimension size;

    Graphical g;
    public WordTest() {
        timer = new Thread(this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void run() {
    Thread me = Thread.currentThread();


    while( timer == me ){

        try{
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(100L);
    }//end try
    catch( InterruptedException intEx ){
intEx.printStackTrace();
    }
        try{
            size = g.currentDeviceScreenSize(this);
            g.postInvalidate();
        }
        catch(NullPointerException n){

        }

if(size.width!=0){
    break;
}

}//end while

}//end method run.
    /**
     * 
     * @param context The Context, usually the activity invoking this call.
     * @param pathname The path to the image file in the assets folder.
     * If the image called bitmap.png is in a folder called bitmap inside the assets folder,
     * then the pathname will be bitmap/bitmap.png
     * @return the loaded bitmap
     */
      public static Bitmap loadImageFromAssets(Context context,String pathname){

        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream;
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try{
            inputStream = assetManager.open(pathname);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        }//end try
        catch(IOException exception){
            return null;
        }
          return bitmap;

      }




    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        g = new Graphical(this);
        setContentView(g);
    }



}

class Graphical extends View {
WordTest test;
    /**
     * Render the passed drawable, transformed.
     *
     * @param context app context
     */
    public Graphical(WordTest test) {
        super(test);
        setMinimumWidth(760);
        setMinimumHeight(935);
    }

    public static Dimension currentDeviceScreenSize(Activity context){

        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= 13){
        Display display = context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();   
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int w = size.x;
        int h = size.y;
        return new Dimension(size.x,size.y);
        }
        else{
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();               
            return new Dimension(display.getWidth(),display.getHeight());   
        }
    }    
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public Dimension _currentDeviceScreenSize(Activity context){

        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= 13){
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        return new Dimension(metrics.widthPixels,metrics.heightPixels);
        }
        else{
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();               
            return new Dimension(display.getWidth(),display.getHeight());   
        }
    }
    private LGraphics _draw() {
        WordTest test = (WordTest) getContext();
        Bitmap map = Bitmap.createBitmap(900, 1300, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        LGraphics graphics = new LGraphicsAndroid2D(map);

        graphics.drawBitmap(WordTest.loadImageFromAssets(getContext(), "images/WelcomeView.png"), 0, 0,700,1000);
        graphics.setColor(LColor.green);
        graphics.drawArc(50, 50, 100,150,0,210);
        graphics.setColor(LColor.blue);//ty
        LFont font = LFont.getFont("Helvetica", LFont.STYLE_BOLD, 30);
        graphics.setFont(font);
        graphics.drawString(test.size.width+","+test.size.height, 10, 90);

        graphics.setColor(LColor.lightGray);
        graphics.draw3DRect(50, 300, 100, 90, true);
        graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
        graphics.setColor(LColor.white);
        graphics.fill3DRect(50+4, 300+4, 100-8, 90-8, false);
        graphics.drawBitmap(WordTest.loadImageFromAssets(test,    "images/LetterBoxHolder.png"), 200, 200,320,250);
        graphics.drawBitmap(WordTest.loadImageFromAssets(test, "images/Kings-Crown.jpg"),           300, 600,200,200);

        return graphics;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        LGraphics g = _draw();
        canvas.drawBitmap(g.getBitmap(), 2, 2,g.getPaint());

        }
        }
```

Please, what am I doing wrong or am I supposed to invoke calls for the screen size only outside an Activity?

Comment: You should try calling the methods that calculate the screen dimensions from the main thread.

Comment: you are getting orignial width and height onWindowsFocusChanged() in this method .This method is called after onCreate().when showing the view. called your view.getwidth() and view.getHeight().

Answer (score 0):

So here is what i am guessing

in your onCreate method, there is no

```
setContentView(View);
```

and since the content view is not created, therefore you will always end up with `height = 0` and `width = 0`

Comment: @gbenroscience you need both, buddy. Why don't you give it a try first ?

Comment: Please who can help.This is urgent

Answer (score 0):

use that code

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
         width = display.getWidth();
         height = display.getHeight();
```